# Zabbix - custom performance counters

Tags: c#, asp.net, performancecounter, zabbix, perfmon

Can I use Zabbix just like perfmon? 
I want to add custom performanceCounters to my code and gather the data in zabbix instead of perfmon.
I'm currently trying a number of different approaches for collecting perfomance data from a webfarm and this is one of the options I'm considering.

Comment: Is https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/perfcounters what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I tried running zabbix agent on my local machine and did manage to prove that zabbix collects the custom performance counters from my code, provided they were registered. It works for both active and passive zabbix agent.